# Error Building Admin Menus (Joomla 3)

Tags: joomla, menu, widget, admin

Fresh install of Joomla 3. Widgetkit and Zoo (Yootheme) both install 'successfully' except for "error building admin menus", meaning they're inoperable.

Normal responses have been to delete items on database and try again. But I have no items relating to either in database 'jos_menu'. Tried deleting all references to widgetkit/zoo on database and FTP, then re-installing many many times and no joy.

Have tried various resources around the net and found exact problem but no solution. I would be hugely grateful.

Thanks in advance, N

Answer (score 0):

There were significant changes between Joomla 3.1 (the current STS release) and 3.0 (the previous one). What version are you running? My best guess would be that you're probably running 3.1 and YOOTheme has not updated WidgetKit or the theme you have chosen quite yet, or you have an outdated version of that plugin.

Solution? Make sure that you're running the latest supported version as reported by YOOTheme for your selected Theme and for WidgetKit.

According to their site, the latest WidgetKit does actually support 3.1, so be sure to download that version directly from their site, not from any third parties.

If my assessment is totally off, let me know. :) I'm sure we can figure out the real answer together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Don, however I had thought of this. The version of Zoo/Widgetkit is the most current and downloaded from their website. Unusually, the templates install absolutely fine. So no worries there. I'm running Joomla 3.1.1. And always get 'Error building admin menus' whichever way I try to install...